# Redshift COUNT(DISTINCT()). Count Unique Dates for each ID

Tags: sql, count, unique, distinct, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to do a distinct count of dates for each ID in my table. I tried this code but it's not returning the correct output.

```
SELECT *
, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY "video_id" ORDER BY "date") AS "distinct_count_date"
FROM mytable
;
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you need :

```
select video_id, count(distinct date)
from mytable
group by video_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @yogesh. I should have add more details. <br> I should have add more details. With the code you provided, it creates duplicates. I have also "age_group" and "gender" as variables. I need to have the count of unique dates regardless of the "age_group" and "gender" (or any other variables I could have).